# Windows - Can't find file on PATH, '.' not in PATH

Tags: windows, perl

I installed a package (Strawberry Perl) and added its bin directory (**C:\Strawberry\perl\bin**) to the environment variables. cpan is a package manager, its in there as `cpan.bat`.

When I try to run it, heres what happens:

```
C:\Users\horse> cpan -fi "DBD::mysql"
Can't find C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat on PATH, '.' not in PATH.
```

Its obviously finding the file because how else would it know its exact location: `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat`

If I try running `cpan.bat` directory like this:

```
C:\Users\horse> C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat  -fi "DBD::mysql"
Can't find C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat on PATH, '.' not in PATH.
```

Same issue. I don't understand why it needs a '.' in the PATH, but I added it there to see what would happen, and its no longer saying anything about a '.' but I'm still getting the same issue with it not finding cpan.bat:

```
C:\Users\horse> cpan
Can't find C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat on PATH.
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Comment: I've removed the batch-file tag because a) batch scripts check the current directory for files before checking the path directory, and b) the Windows "file not in PATH" error message is `_____ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: This problem is occurring for other batch files in there like `perldoc.bat`. I'm very confused that outputs the location of the file and then tells me it can't find it. So you're saying that its 1 of these 4 possible scenarios. Its a batch file, thats for sure. I can run it by going into the folder and double clicking on it.

Comment: I know basically nothing about Perl, but from what I've seen online, it looks like you either misconfigured something when installing it or there's a settings file you need to update. Either way, this is a Perl problem, not a batch problem.

Comment: Yeah its definitely not a batch file problem, cpan.bat runs just fine when I double click it manually. You think its a Perl problem? It looks like I might have two perl.exe files installed, when I run `get-command perl`, it says its located in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\perl.exe`. So its using the version that came with a Git install it looks like. Weird because that git folder isn't actually in my environment variables. Not sure what to do about this.

Comment: SomethingDark: I fixed the problem, you were right it was a problem with perl. I'll post details in an answer.

Answer (score 16):

The problem was I had two perl.exe files installed, when I ran `get-command perl`, it said its located in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\perl.exe`. So its using the version that came with with what looks like a CygWin install (C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ is loaded with unix like commands). So I removed `perl.exe` from `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Legend mate! Thanks for posting your resolution and not just answering that you fixed your own problem :D

I was getting this issue trying to run perltidy through Atom Beautify