# Chocolatey perl OSType.pm

Tags: flutter, dart, perl, lcov

I have Perl script to make test coverage reports with LCOV. The problem is when I run in on my Windows, it shows next error:

```
PS C:\Projects\project> perl test_coverage.pl
=============================
LCOV_HOME: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools
Can't locate Perl/OSType.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Perl::OSType module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/local/share/perl5/s
ite_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.32) at C:\ProgramData
\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\lcov line 73.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\lcov line 73.
Can't locate Perl/OSType.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Perl::OSType module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/local/share/perl5/s
ite_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.32) at C:\ProgramData
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\genhtml line 75.
=============================
Can't locate Perl/OSType.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Perl::OSType module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/local/share/perl5/s
ite_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.32) at C:\ProgramData
\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\lcov line 73.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\lcov line 73.
Can't locate Perl/OSType.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Perl::OSType module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/local/share/perl5/s
ite_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.32 /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.32) at C:\ProgramData
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\genhtml line 75.
```

I don't really understand how to "install" Perl::OSType module.

I've been using this https://fredgrott.medium.com/lcov-on-windows-7c58dda07080
to get through install process.

The Strawberry Perl was installed with `choco install lcov` command. And I've set enviroment `GENHTML` variable with `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\genhtml` path.

LCOV_HOME is set `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools`

I'm trying to make sure everything is all right to simply use my script, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: That is a Perl module you need to install on your system for that code to run.

Comment: At its simplest, you would do `cpan Perl::OSType`. Which should install the module if it is in the cpan library.

Comment: @TLP I believe I don't have CPAN installed, I have `C:\Strawberry\cpan\sources` folder, but it is empty

Comment: Just run the command suggested by TLP.

Comment: @pts `Can't find C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat on PATH, '.' not in PATH.`

Comment: @pts https://stackoverflow.com/a/40580961/10766511 this seems to fix the PATH probelm, but I still figuring out scripts issues. But anyway thank you both! It was really helpful to get on the right path!